# text not contained in div without margin: 0 auto

Tags: html, css

I have a container for a website i'm working on and I cant seem to make the text conform to the container unless I place a `margin: 0 auto` in the parent container which i don't want to as it will mess up my positioning. Is there any other way to fit the text in?

This is the code:

```css
div.TadobaWrapper {
  background-color: #44511E;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
div.Tadoba img{
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 105px;
  left: 320px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
}
div.TadobaContainer {
  width: 35%;
  height: 270px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 135px;
  left: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px;
}
div.TadobaContainer section h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 600px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
div.TadobaContainer section p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px 30px 0;
}
div.TadobaContainer section a {
  color: #54E112;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 20px 10px;
}
div.TadobaContainer section a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="TadobaWrapper">
 <div class="Tadoba"> <img src="Tadoba/21.JPG"/>
 <div class="TadobaContainer">
  <section>
    <h1>Tadoba Andhari Tiger Reserve</h1>
    <p> Tadoba Andhari Tiger Reserve is a wild animal reservation in the 
     Chandrapur district of Maharashtra state in India, widely known as 
     Maharashtra’s oldest and largest national park. The park contains many 
     different animals including, Tigers, leopards, Dear and various other 
      wild animals.   </p>
     <a href="#" class="lrnmoretadoba">Learn More</a> </section>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Updated Code. I hope it will help to you.

```css
div.TadobaWrapper{
background-color: #44511E;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
}
div.Tadoba img{
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 105px;
    left: 320px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
}
div.TadobaContainer{
    width: 35%;
  
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 135px;
    left: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px;
}
div.TadobaContainer section h1{
font-size: 25px;
    /* width: 600px; */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /* margin: auto; */
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
div.TadobaContainer section p{
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.2vw;
line-height: 18px;
text-align: justify;
padding: 10px 30px 0;
}
div.TadobaContainer section a{
color: #54E112;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
float: right;
margin: 0 20px 10px;
}
div.TadobaContainer section a:hover{
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="TadobaWrapper">
 <div class="Tadoba"> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/235985/pexels-photo-235985.jpeg"/>
 <div class="TadobaContainer">
  <section>
    <h1>Tadoba Andhari Tiger Reserve</h1>
    <p> Tadoba Andhari Tiger Reserve is a wild animal reservation in the 
     Chandrapur district of Maharashtra state in India, widely known as 
     Maharashtra’s oldest and largest national park. The park contains many 
     different animals including, Tigers, leopards, Dear and various other 
      wild animals.   </p>
     <a href="#" class="lrnmoretadoba">Learn More</a> </section>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `position` of `div.TadobaContainer` from `relative` to `absolute`, so it becomes this:

```
div.TadobaContainer {
    width: 35%;
    height: 270px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 135px;
    left: 40%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

The reasons the `<h1>` title perhaps doesn't fall within the `TadobaContainer` is its fixed width. There might also be too much text to fit in the container.